# jQuery - Scroll to moving div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 50 record of data in div elements and I just see 10 at the beginning, the other 40 are display: none. When I click to the next, then the next button scrolling down and 10 new div will be visible. The problem is that, if I open more record, what can be visible on the screen, then the next button runs out of the screen.
So when I load the page first time the distance of the next button from the top of the page for example 300 px. Then I click on next and this distance will be 600 and finally runs out, but the page should scroll to the bottom position of the next button. An other problem is that, at the end not always 10 record will appear, so a static method for the problem can't be correct.
So this for example almost good:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 2*$('#next-button').offset().top-$(document).height()}, 1000);
```

But at the end, when there are less then 10 record it scrolls down with 10 and just for the next click (when there is no element) will scroll down with the proper height.
Are there any method to scroll down always to the bottom of a div even if the div is moving? It would be better without any plugin.

Here is more code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content">New elements appears here if there was click</div>
<div id="next-button">Next 10</div>
<div id="footer">Lot of data</div>
</body>
```

Js:

```
$("#next-button").click(function() {
  //Scroll down the new results and after:
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 2*$('#next-button').offset().top-$(document).height()}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I would just put the next button after all of the results so it is always at the bottom of the shown results

Comment: Yes, there is. But the page should scrolls down, when new elements appear

Comment: you can make the page scroll down when next is clicked, the logic would be something like clicked next, get next scrollTop, show additional results, scroll to the next scrollTop position you saved from before